# In hbase, can the presence of a large table affect the performance of other smaller tables?

Tags: hbase

In our lower environment we have a single table with 100 000 000 rows and a straight scan of this table can return about 2 800 rows a second. In our production environment we have a table of 100 000 000 rows and another of around 4 billion rows, and a scan of the smaller table yields only 1 000 rows per second. In both cases there is no other activity going on, so is it the presence of the large table that accounts for the dip in performance?

Both tables have a single column family, the large table has 400 columns but a record will only have 1 of them populated. The smaller table has a single column and that column is always populated.

Comment: Are you doing row-only scan or also including columns in both cases. more importantly, has your 'slower' table had a lot of deletes, and how frequently has it been major-compacted?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Columns are included in both cases (each row has 1 and only 1 column), there have been no deletes on either table, and a major compaction was performed before the scans on both tables. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry don't know what else to suggest then. Did I understand correctly that in the small environment the table has only one column, but in the large environment the table has potentially 400 different columns, but only ONE can be populated at a time for each row? If that's the case maybe the delay is due to this?

Comment: Thanks again. The table on which the scan is performed has one populated column in both environments. In the production environment there is additionally a massive table where each record has one of upto 400 columns, though we don't scan this table.

Comment: Maybe one thing to consider is what sort of workload your production large table is experiencing? Even if you don't scan the large production table, if for example it is hit with lots or writes/etc., then your production cluster allocates too much resources to that workload. If that's the case, you could potentially configure your production environment to allocate more resources to READS, and even more specifically to SCANS. If that's helpful, i can describe how to do it.

Comment: That would be incredibly useful, thank you so much. When we run the export from the table the ability to allocate as much of the resources as possible to scans would definitely help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to specify how much resources HBase allocates to Scans in `hbase-site.xml`. You can do this in two steps: 
1. Specify percentage of resources allocated to reads (as opposed to writes)
2. Specify percentage of READS resources allocated to Scans (rather than Gets)

In the below example, you have 96 CPUs in the whole cluster. You allocate 80% of their attention to Reads, and then 80% of that attention to Scans.

See if this makes any difference for for you.

```
   <property>
        <name>hbase.regionserver.handler.count</name>
        <value>96</value> <!-- roughly # of CPUs in the whole cluster -->
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.ipc.server.callqueue.read.ratio</name>
        <value>0.8</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.ipc.server.callqueue.scan.ratio</name>
        <value>0.8</value>
    </property>
```

Comment: Great stuff, thank you very much, I'll give that a go.